# How to trace rabbitmq end to end between producer and consumer for multiple microservices?

Tags: spring-boot, trace, spring-rabbit

I am using rabbitmq as one of the microservice and for that I want trace the rabbitmq spans,
I have used following dependencies for tracing the rabbitmq spans through opentracing,

```
compile io.opentracing.contrib:opentracing-spring-jaeger-cloud-starter:1.0.1
compile group: 'io.opentracing.contrib', name: 'opentracing-spring-rabbitmq-parent', version: '2.0.5'
```

I am getting only producer side spans for this microservice.
producer

```
Tags routingkey
"" messageid
"null"

component
"rabbitmq"

exchange
"audit_exchange"

span.kind
"producer"
```

I want to get end to end tracing for the request which passed through multiple micro services and one of them is `rabbitmq`

like `microservice1==>rabbitMQ(Producer)==>Microservice2==>rabbitMQ(Consumer)==>Response Service`

How can I achieve this kind of tracing in jaeger UI?

Answer (score 1):

I use `io.opentracing.contrib:opentracing-spring-rabbitmq-starter:3.0.0`.
You can find some documentation [here](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-spring-rabbitmq). With this mechanism I achieved exactly what you asked for.

I found 2 important things to make sure:

1. The rabbit template has to be initialized BEFORE the `RabbitMqTracingAutoConfiguration` is called. In the beginning I had the problem that the bean was not created as the RabbitTemplate was created AFTER the `RabbitMqTracingAutoConfiguration` was called.
2. Not all RestTemplate methods are surrounded with the Aspect. [Here](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-spring-rabbitmq/blob/release-3.0.0/opentracing-spring-rabbitmq/src/main/java/io/opentracing/contrib/spring/rabbitmq/RabbitMqSendTracingAspect.java#L32) you can find an overview of which methods are currently supported. We have currently the problem, that `RabbitTemplate.invoke` is not supported.

Hopefully you find this helpful.